# Failed to create the part's controls in Eclipse Mars error

Tags: java, eclipse

[image]

I am using Eclipse Mars editor in Fedora 24 OS, and when I am trying to click on the JSP files I got "Failed to create parts error" due to this I am unable to open JSP files, I have also attached a screenshot. can anyone help me out?

This is the error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: " o"
    at java.net.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.utils.ProjectResolver.getLocationByURI(ProjectResolver.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.utils.ProjectResolver.getLocationByURI(ProjectResolver.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.utils.ImageResolver.getResolvedURL(ImageResolver.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.utils.ImageResolver.initializeImage(ImageResolver.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.figurehandler.ImgFigureHandler.initializeImage(ImgFigureHandler.java:38)
```

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed error message. If there is edit your question and add the full message.

Comment: Eclipse contains "editors", it is not itself an "editor". Right-click on the file. What editor is it trying to open, and is it the one you intended? Push the button labelled "Details" for some relevant log output.

Comment: hello greg-449, I have added the error message. please check.

Comment: Looks similiar to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=356841

Comment: I fixed the issue by selecting defective .jsp file and right clicked and it has option called 'Open With' and selected 'JSP Editor' and done! its fixed my issue. I hope it will fixed yours too no matter what version of Eclipse you are using but I'm using Eclipse Mars. Please let me know if this fixed for you or  not

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same error message displayed after I installed Spring Tool suite into Eclipse Oxygen (4.7.3a). I solved it by installing liwebkitgtk 3.0.0. I am a kubuntu user so I use apt package manager;

```
   sudo apt update && sudo apt install libwebkitgtk-3.0-0
```

I believe you should use yum package manager as you are using fedora which is redhat based